# Mixing Hyperbolic Functions and Logarithmic Functions, and using them to prove equalities using the definition of Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

Got a question regarding using the definition of a hyperbolic function to prove other equalities based on a given equation.

Given:
$$
x=\ln\left[\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]
$$

Find:
$$ e^x $$ and $$ \frac{1}{e^x} $$

And HENCE prove that:
$$
\sinh x=\tan(\theta)
$$

I know I need to use inverse hyperbolic functions to solve this, but I don't know where the definition comes in. Can someone maybe explain it to me?

Comment: What did you try? Can you compute $e^x$? Hint : $\forall a>0,\;e^{\ln a}=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [definition of hyperbolic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_analytic_expressions):
$$\sinh x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
,
$$\sinh x = \frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2})-\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2})}}{2} = \frac{(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}))^2-1}{2{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2})}} = -1/\tan (\pi/2 + \theta) = \tan(\theta) $$